# How to tell Botium to use a custom session id in DialogflowCX?

Tags: dialogflow-cx, botium-box

We are using Botium Bindings with DialogflowCX connector, and we need to tell Botium to use a session id in a custom format (e.g. abc-xyz). Currently Botium/DialogflowCX connector generates automatically its own session id for each utterance. Is there a way to do this?

I didn't find anything about it in DialogflowCX or Botium repositories.